# Samba which CPU performance is used?

Tags: php, linux, soap, samba, smb

I have 2 Servers, the 1st is runing a PHP-Script, the 2nd contents a Java-Program to analyse pictures, which needs more performance.

I want to make the PHP-Script use this Java Program, at first time i decided to use SOAP-Connection between the 2 servers, then i though maybe it will be better and faster to use it as it is on the same server and mounted this using Samba

```
mount cifs -t smb://IP/path/to/java/process
```

so now i'm wondering which CPU performance will be used when runing the script locally ? the CPU where is the Java-Program or the PHP-Script.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Does a Samba mount incur CPU overhead?  Typically - not much.  Is it more efficient to share data with a Samba mount than to generate, send, receive and process a munch of SOAP messages?  Almost certainly :)  I'm not sure what you're asking here...

Answer (score 1):

No, running a program from a CIFS mount does not make the program run on the server that it's being mounted from. As Charles Babbage famously put it:

> I am not able rightly to apprehend the kind of confusion of ideas that could provoke such a question.

Comment: the idea still not impossible, because you can use load balancer, or pipe it to a script or cron job, which make the process runs under the other server!

Comment: No, I'm sorry, but that still makes no sense. A load balancer is a completely unrelated piece of technology, and "a script or cron job" would still have to run on the other server. CIFS is not a method of running jobs remotely, and there's no way around that.

Comment: you still not understanding my question!

Comment: I'm pretty sure I understand your question just fine, it's just a pretty strange question, and the answer is "no, it doesn't work like that".